# Boxplot (ggplot2) not working as expected

Tags: r, ggplot2, boxplot

I'm trying to plot a simple boxplot where I get 15 boxplots for respondents age of 15 "Cadernos" (15 surveys, surveys A, B, C .. to O). But that's not working as expected.
I have already tried to switch places to the "Cadernos" (surveys) and "Idade" (age) variables.
Any idea? What I expected was 15 boxplots in the vertical axis.

The code I'm using is the follow:

```
library(ggplot2)

select_base %>% 
  ggplot(aes(Idade,Caderno)) +
  geom_boxplot()
```

the plot I get is the following:

[image]

Comment: I don't think that code generated the plot: the x and y variables are reversed in the code versus the plot.

Comment: Also it looks like `Idade` is a variable of type character or factor, instead of numeric. What does `str(select_base)` show you?

Comment: @neilfws You're right, the code that generrates that plot has those variables switched, I slipped-up.
About the type of varible, ```str(select_base)```  returns: 

'data.frame': 2876 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ Caderno: chr  "N" "N" "M" "M" ...
 $ Idade  : chr  "15" "15" "15" "15" ...

So, yes, they're characters, would that be affecting the code? Tks in advance

Comment: Yes, you need the y-variable to be of type numeric. You may be able to convert the column using `as.numeric()`, but it's better to figure out why R read it in as a character in the first place - for example, does the data file contain something other than numbers in that column.

Comment: @neilfws thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure that you did not provide your data, but you may try

```
select_base %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = Caderno, y = Idade, group = Caderno)) +
  geom_boxplot()
```

For example using data `dummy` it will be like plot below

```
dummy <- data.frame(
  x = rnorm(50),
  y = rep(c("a","b","c","d","e"),10)
)
dummy %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = y,y = x,  group = y)) +
  geom_boxplot()
```

[image]